# How to declare a function which takes an array by reference as an argument in C++?

Tags: c++, function, arguments

I have this code with function which takes two-dimensional array by reference and its bounds by template as an arguments:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void Foo(); // I need it here

int main()
{
    char Space[10][10];
    Foo(Space);

    return 0;
}

template <size_t rows, size_t cols>
void Foo(char (&array)[rows][cols])
{
    size_t j;
    size_t i;
    for (j = 0; j < rows; j++)
    {
        for (i = 0; i < cols; i++)
        {          
            array[i][j] = '.';
        }
    }
}
```

I need to declare this function before main code block, and then define after it. How to do this properly?

Comment: Why not avoid the problem and put the definition first?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just put that declaration up where you want it:

```
#include <stdio.h>
template <size_t rows, size_t cols>
void Foo(char (&array)[rows][cols]);

int main()
{
    char Space[10][10];
    Foo(Space);

    return 0;
}

template <size_t rows, size_t cols>
void Foo(char (&array)[rows][cols])
{
    size_t j;
    size_t i;
    for (j = 0; j < rows; j++)
    {
        for (i = 0; i < cols; i++)
        {          
            array[i][j] = '.';
        }
    }
}
```

[Godbolt example](https://godbolt.org/z/z44TzPMxx)

Answer (score 2):

Just remove the function body:

```
template <size_t rows, size_t cols>
void Foo(char (&array)[rows][cols]);
```

Comment: "_Just remove the function body_" _may_ be misinterpreted as you suggest to remove the function body from the current definition when you mean OP should copy the definition to the top of the program and then remove the function body from that copy, leaving only the declaration (I assume).